# Pulling financial data from a JSON API in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I am very new to python and I am trying to pull specific data from an API

I would like to extract, for example the  3y_SharpRatio. I have tried:

```
import requests
import json

VTI = requests.get("https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/VTI.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX").json()

print(VTI["3y_SharpRatio"])
```

But receive the following error:

```
KeyError                                  
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-7-4dc0323003b9> in <module> 
----> 1 print(VTI["3y_SharpRatio"]) 
KeyError: '3y_SharpRatio'
```

Any help welcome, sorry if it is a very basic issue!

Comment: Print only VTI an check if 3y_ShartRatio is really an attribute of the json: ```json.dumps (VTI)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've included your API key in the post which is bad from a security point of view, but does allow me to see that `3y_SharpRatio` is here:

```
ETF_Data    
    Performance 
        3y_Volatility   "12.37"
        3y_ExpReturn    "0.00"
        3y_SharpRatio   "1.03"
        Returns_3Y  "14.14"
```

So you need

```
print(VTI['ETF_Data']['Performance']['3y_SharpRatio']
```

Comment: Thank you! (Not my API Key, only a test)

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
import json

VTI = requests.get("https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/VTI.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX").json()
# print (json.dumps(VTI, indent = 20))
# print (json.dumps(VTI["ETF_Data"], indent = 20))
# print (json.dumps(VTI["ETF_Data"]['Performance'], indent = 20))
print (VTI["ETF_Data"]["Performance"]['3y_SharpRatio'])
'1.03'
```

I have commented out the lines which you can use over steps one by one to dig down to find your key.